# Why are tatoos impermissible?

Tags: halal-haram

There is another article on this site which tries to explain why a tatoo is haram but I don’t think it does a good job. Two points are made:
1.It prevents Wudu/ghusl
2.It changes the creation of Allah

However, ink in tattoos is inserted into the dermis layer of the skin so where the tatoo is located does not prevent water from reaching the skin.
Also, some scholars have allowed people to get plastic surgery etc e.g to sort facial features out after an accident or something like that which is changing the creation of Allah too.

Some people already have tattoos and convert to Islam it is a bit unfair for the ink to prevent such a person from praying or for this person to be at blame for changing oneself even though they may not have been aware of the consequences of their actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tattoos are haram because the Prophet told us they are haram. The rest are reasonings we attempt to find. One of those reasons is that it is changing the creation of Allah.

Plastic surgery is also haram for the same reason. But, scholars allow it in exceptional cases for something necessary. There is a difference between compelling circumstances and normal circumstances. Everything is allowed in compelling circumstances.

As for converts who had tattoos before, again, that is an exceptional circumstance. Their wudu counts because they made their mistake before they knew anything. Exceptional circumstance are not like normal circumstances.

The exception for a convert who did something in the past without knowing it was wrong does not apply to a Muslim who knowingly committed his sin.

Comment: Alright thank you